# How to define multiple servlet-mapping for 2 group / module of controllers

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to design a multiple module project with spring mvc.

I don't want to involve the OSGi or springsource DM server. I just want to separate the controller classes into a couple of packages.

```
com.myproject
  ├─ moldule1
  │  └─ controller
  │      └─ controller classes for moldule1 ...
  └─moldule2
     └─ controller
         └─ controller classes for moldule2 ...
```

Then the controllers under module1 can be accessed by .../module1/controller/action.do and the controllers under module2 can be accessed by .../module2/controller/action.do.

Can somebody point me to an example of such a structure? Especially how to configure the servlet-mapping in web.xml.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add multiple controller in the same project, Please enable controller auto scan mode in `dispatcher-servlet.xml` like this,

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject" />
```

then segregate your controller the way you want it,

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/module1/controller")
public class Module1Controller {

   // Define your specific HTTP RequestMapping 

   @RequestMapping(value = "/action.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String foo(HttpSerlvetRequest request, Map<String, Object> map)){

       // define your method behaviour
       return "sample";
   }
}
```

For Second Module2Controller add it in the same package in your project,

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/module2/controller")
    public class Module2Controller {

       // Define your specific HTTP RequestMapping 
    }
```

Comment: I tested your solution and it worked fine.

It's really a simple implement. But I never think about it until you pointed out.

Thank you very much, Vig.

Comment: Welcome Daniel, Hope, everything should be clear now.